# ¿Qué origen tiene la expresión "ya te cargó el payaso"?

Tags: méxico, palabras-raras, expresiones-fijas

Entiendo que "*ya te cargó el payaso*" expresa fracaso total, problemas que no pueden ser resueltos, etc. ¿Qué orígen tiene esta expresión? ¿Es lenguaje no ofensivo?

Comment: Yo sigo pensando en que su origen es la pelicula de eso, al menos no encuentro evidencia de que haya sido usada antes , aunque si alguien tiene un escrito anterior a los 90s que registre el uso de esta expresion me convencere Porque tambien hay falsos origenes como el que se anduvo diciendo de la palabra quesadilla, lo del payaso de rodeo se me hace semejante, en Mexico no tenemos rodeo, al menos no al estilo americano asi que se me hace dificil que este sea el origen de la expresion de ya te cargo el payaso

Comment: Al menos en Coahuila y en Nuevo León (donde nací y donde viví) si hay rodeo al estilo americano, con payasos y todo :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**[Este sitio](http://www.sabiduriadeescalera.com/?p=1642)** ofrece una explicación interesante, y menciona lo primero que se me vino a la mente, el payaso **ESO** de Stephen King que es un personaje aterrador y ciertamente creo yo que coincide con las connotaciones negativas de la expresión, sin embargo aparentemente la frase es mas antigua que la película (o el libro).

En resumen un origen creíble y razonable de la expresión es la existencia del **"Payaso de Rodeo"**.

El rodeo es un deporte altamente peligroso y en ciertos eventos el jinete puede salir bastante lastimado por caídas, pisotones/patadas de caballos o siendo corneado por los toros. Por todo esto se crearon los Payasos de Rodeo, para distraer al toro cuando el jinete se encuentra vulnerable y en los peores casos, **"cargar"** al jinete lesionado para llevarlo con los paramédicos...

Y pues no es lenguaje ofensivo exactamente (si lo sería decir "ya te cargo la chingada" por ejemplo), pero si es una frase algo informal, por lo que no es algo que sea apropiado usar en una conversación "seria".

Comment: +1 No sé si haya una explicación exacta, pero ésta es la que más sentido tiene (hasta ahora).

Answer (score 2):

Creo que proviene de "ya te cargo la chingada" pero como "chingada" es una grosería entonces se reemplaza por "payaso", de esta forma no dices la grosería y se "oye" menos vulgar. Aun así no es un lenguaje apto para situaciones formales asi que en estos casos debes abstenerte de usarlo.

Comment: Gracias, +1. Pero ¿qué tiene de particular un payaso? Esa es la pregunta.

Comment: Muchas veces, los dichos casuales o coloquiales no necesariamente hacen sentido.  Mi impresión en este caso (al igual que muchos dichos guatemaltecos), es que "payaso" no sirve más que para esconder la vulgaridad.

Comment: Ok, es un eufemismo que todo el mundo me entendería, por lo que veo.

Answer (score 2):

No a todos los niños les gustan los payasos, así que hace años a los niños les contrataban payasos para sus fiestas y, aunque le tuvieran miedo, hacían que se tomaran la foto con el payaso. Por tanto, el payaso los tenía que cargar.

Por eso dicen "ya te cargó el payaso" aunque el niño llorara.

Answer (score 1):

Hace mucho años en los 1900's   en ciudad de México se comenzó una practica para cobrar deudas, y esta consistía que cuando una persona debía dinero y no cumplía sus pagos había una agencia de cobranza que se caracterizaba por ridiculizar al deudor con el fin de evidenciarlo públicamente que debía dinero.  Entre las acciones que realizaba era contratar a un payaso que te siguiera por todo un día en todas tus actividades, a la iglesia, al café, en el tren, en un restaurante, etc, siempre estaría esa persona disfrazada de payaso a tu lado y se identificaba que eras un deudor moroso.  Esta situación se hizo muy famosa hasta en periódicos aparecía importantes personalidades del México de los 1900's con un payaso a lado.  Fue donde mucha gente comenzó a decir "Ya le pusieron payaso" o "Ya se lo cargo el payaso" para evitar el uso de la mala palabra "Chin...."

Comment: Muy interesante ¿Hay una fuente bibliográfica que soporte este hecho?

Answer (score 0):

en los años de la decada de los 70 s un servidor estudiaba medicina en la Cd. de Monterrey...en ese tiempo habia un programa de un señor llamado Horacio Alvarado Ortiz....al parecer el prog. se llamaba ..costumbres de mi pueblo...y me llamo la atencion de como los habitantes de un pueblo ...parece ser ...villa de santiago...usaban ....El mono rojo...que en este caso vendria siendo el payaso...y me llamo mucho la atencion de la creatividad de la gente para solucionar algunos problemas  en este caso de gente tracalera y abusadora que se hace loquita y no quiere pagar al igual que los describe Jose Juis Garza solo que con mas anterioridad.  tambien es importante la reaccion del deudor...ya que no tiene otra salida mas que pagar o quedar muy mal parado con la sociedad..

Comment: fe de errata...dr. arriaga dice ...jose luis garza hace referencia desde 1900.. o sea a principios del siglo....ese prog. lo vi en la decada de los 70 s..

Comment: Interesante respuesta, aunque convendría redactarla un poco mejor.