# "Hace sentido" o "tiene sentido"

Tags: gramática, expresiones

Estaba leyendo los comentarios sobre la pregunta [Te cargó el payaso](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/3419/qu%C3%A9-origen-tiene-la-expresi%C3%B3n-ya-te-carg%C3%B3-el-payaso) y me causó dolor ver en este foro la expresión "hace sentido" y ya que este Stack está destinado al conocimiento y buen uso del Español, propongo esta pregunta que aunque discutida en otros sitios aquí aun no la discutimos.

Es correcto decir:

> "Hace sentido"

o solo es correcto decir

> "Tiene sentido"

Comment: I always hear "tiene sentido." I have never heard "hacer sentido". Nunca he escuchado "hacer sentido" en ninguna forma.

Comment: En latinoamérica cada vez es más frecuente escuchar personas usando  este anglicismo.

Comment: Looks like too many people have the same question. It just got the Popular Question badge with 1000 views.

Comment: I wonder why. I've never heard it and it doesn't occur to me to use it and I'm not a native speaker... or, mejor dicho, I'm about 25% native speaker.

Comment: La Dra. Ana Maria Polo del programa de television Caso Cerrado siempre dice"hace sentido" y cuando escucho esa frase me quiero dar un volantin. Que nadie le ha avisado la manera correca de hablar el Español?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Para mi como nativo la que suena bien es `tener sentido`. La expresión `hacer sentido` me *chirría* al oído, aunque no mucho.

Un búsqueda rápida revela [este link](http://www.academia.org.mx/espin/Detalle?id=26) de la Academia de la Lengua Mexicana que dice

> **La frase generalizada en español es "tener sentido"**. La expresión "hacer sentido" es una traducción literal de la forma en inglés "to make sense". Aunque ambas expresiones tienen el mismo significado, se recomienda emplear "tener sentido", ya que es la forma patrimonial del español; además, **el verbo hacer no tiene ninguna acepción que permita usarlo con el significado que tiene en la frase "hacer sentido"**.

Y [Fundeú BBVA](http://www.fundeu.es/consulta/hace-sentido-o-tiene-sentido-700/) corrobora que `hacer sentido` es una traducción literal del inglés, por lo que implícitamente sugiere que sólo "tener sentido" es la forma correcta.

También [esta web](http://espanolsinmisterios.blogspot.com/2011/10/hacer-sentido-no-tiene-sentido.html) acusa a `hacer sentido` de ser solo una "traducción descuidada de una expresión inglesa".

Comment: Sería también interesante comprobar si "hacer sentido" se usa más en países hispanohablantes con mayores influencias de lengua anglosajona.

Comment: No creo que se le pueda atribuir este fenómeno exclusivamente al inglés, porque en portugués se dice "fazer sentido" y no "ter sentido".

Comment: @x1704e, es un punto a tener en cuenta. Sin embargo, yo nunca he escuchado "hacer sentido" en España, que limita con Portugal (aunque quizá sea más común en regiones como Coruña, más cercanas a Portugal que Madrid). Las referencias que enlazo recogen el uso de "hacer sentido" en México  y Puerto Rico, por lo que sería de entender que el inglés tendría más culpa que el portugués para estos casos particulares. Ignoro si otros países latinos cercanos a Brasil usan la expresión por influencia del portugués.

Comment: @Diego  Sí, en Venezuela he escuchado "hacerle sentido", mas no recuerdo haber oído simplemente "hacer sentido".

Comment: @DGaleano ¿recibes este comentario? [Probando uno dos, para verificar que no se reciben]

Answer (score 2):

Yendo directo al punto la palabra "hace" viene del verbo hacer, lo que significa realizar o llevar una acción. Por otro lado, la palabra "tiene" viene del verbo tener lo que nos da a saber que se conserva  consigo. Con esto la afirmación hace sentido alude a que esto, ayuda a que lo que esta en cuestión puede obtener un sentido. Mientras, el tiene sentido nos permite entender que lo que se encuentra en cuestión ya ha cobrado sentido (en sí mismo).

Answer (score 1):

(Yo no tengo la reputación para comentar, sé que esto no es en verdad una respuesta)

En portugués se dice "faz sentido" y "faz" tiene un sentido muy similar al "hacer" y de "make". La herramienta de etimología del Google confirma que hacer y fazer vienen de *faciere* (lat) ¿En verdad que "hace sentido" es solo un anglicismo? Quizás sea algo también tomado del portugués o algo conectado con el sentido antiguo de hacer.

Comment: Como dice Diego en su comentario a la otra respuesta, la expresión *hace sentido* prácticamente no existe en España, y parece que se usa mayoritariamente en Puerto Rico y México. Esto son indicios de que probablemente la influencia sea del inglés.

Answer (score 0):

Lo conozco como:

- "**Me/le/les/nos** hace sentido"(=**a mí/=a él/ella/ellos/nosotros**)(probablemente incorrecta pero se usa)

Lo he escuchado cuando una persona hace una reflexión sobre algo que otra dijo y que le gatilla una cierta identificación o con la cual se identifica, por lo tanto el sentido es algo que lo capta el receptor, no es una cualidad intrínseca del emisor, es algo que ocurre en su relación con el otro, es equivalente a tiene sentido AHORA **para mí/el/ella/ellos/nosotros** lo que dijo a pesar que antes NO.

- Lo que dijo ahora me hace sentido(=ahora sí que estoy de acuerdo con lo que dijo, he tomado conciencia de algo que antes no había visto en cuanto a lo que dijo, ahora encuentro que tiene razón)
- "Tiene sentido"(=para todos o para nadie, cualidad absoluta u omite para **mí/el/ella/ellos/nosotros** pero quiere decir igualmente que es para alguien determinado o que su afirmación la única que importa)
- "Hace sentido"(queriendo decir "tiene sentido" o que está "teniendo sentido")(claramente incorrecta y se usa por costumbre, porque otra gente lo dice)

Se centra en algo que está ocurriendo constantemente o que tiene todavía vigencia para alguien al contrario de un tener como una cualidad absoluta.

> “La acción de darse cuenta, comprender e interpretar algo que antes no veía. Lo que **me hace sentido**, me es familiar y me permite actuar con naturalidad.

[hacer-sentido](https://hacesentido.com/hacer-sentido/)

> A: Quizás transmitimos cuando estamos soñando. Quizás es demasiado débil para ser medido, o quizás no sabemos tanto como creemos de nuestro cerebro.

> B: **Eso hace sentido hasta ahora**. Me alegra que uno de nosotros piense así. ─Así que, bueno, estás transmitiendo, todo el mundo está transmitiendo, ..

(=No pensaba eso hasta ahora, eso no me hizo sentido hasta ahora que lo acabas de mencionar/no ha tenido para mí sentido, pero ahora que lo mencionas, sí lo tiene)

[Estudiante de los Sueños](https://books.google.cl/books?id=BV5tDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT146&lpg=PT146&dq=Quiz%C3%A1s+transmitimos+cuando+estamos+so%C3%B1ando.+Quiz%C3%A1s+es+demasiado+d%C3%A9bil+para+ser+medido,+o+quiz%C3%A1s+no+sabemos+tanto+como+creemos+de+nuestro+cerebro.&source=bl&ots=fLN0Ez6JS9&sig=ACfU3U31rllAXcuU25DANPBJwqom3LozEw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi0qYeApuL2AhX2IrkGHdEaCRsQ6AF6BAgCEAM)

Queda aún más evidenciado que es igual a "it/that makes sense now" sin el «se/me/le/nos» porque es algo que está cobrando o cobra sentido para alguien, en este caso para él porque en el libro hablan sólo 2 personas, que quiera involucrar a otros al decirlo de esa forma omitiendo el sujeto, que quiera decir que es algo de la nueva era o generación, que si tiene sentido para él lo tiene para todos o que lo único que importa es que tenga sentido para él y los demás da lo mismo.

También se usa cuando ese algo le permite esclarecer otra cosa(no recuerdo el ej.) o que lo mueve a hacer algo, es común en determinado grupo de gente que es más propensa a expresarse o hablar con tecnicismos, jergas, extranjerismos o formas de hablar del momento.

> La frase sencilla y directa **me hace sentido** porque la crianza que recibí daba valor a lo práctico, a lo “rendidor”, a lo simple y útil. La frase sencilla y directa también **me hace sentido** porque me he predispuesto, en mis años de sociólogo, a asombrarme con juegos de palabras y reconstrucciones que muestran la complejidad que hay detrás de gestos simples. Como todo habitus, el mío es un conjunto de pliegues, buena parte de los cuales he provocado yo mismo, a través de mis búsquedas, mis encuentros, mis asombros. Uno de ellos, uno que **resuena habitualmente en mí** y que me ha inspirado, es el de lo “miserablemente excepcional”, el de “lo que pasa cuando no pasa nada más que…”

> AD: Claro, tu trabajo contiene algo que suena al oído, pero que también **hace sentido**, es decir, **resuena**…