# ¿Es correcto decir «podría haber muerto» refiriéndose a tiempo pasado?

Tags: gramática

Revisando algunos [*tweets*](https://twitter.com/ActualidadRT/status/961999383234408449)  de la cuenta @ActualidadRT, llego a notar el título de una de ellas que dice:

> "Uma Thurman **podría** haber muerto por decapitación"

Lo cual no [tiene](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/15289/hace-sentido-o-tiene-sentido) sentido ya que la palabra  «podría» se refiere a la primera persona del singular (yo) o a la tercera persona del singular (ella, él, ello; usted) del condicional de poder, pero tomando como base el tiempo presento o futuro, no hacia el pasado.

Considero que el uso correcto para esa oración sería:

> "Uma Thurman **pudo** haber muerto por decapitación"

¿Estoy en lo cierto o de igual forma es correcto usar «podría» refiriéndome a un tiempo pasado?

Comment: Flxtr, lo que lo pone en el pasado es el auxiliar "haber".

Answer (score 1):

Ambas son correctas y para mi con significados iguales.

Creo que lo importante es notar que ambas frases usan el verbo poder pero más el auxiliar **"haber"**:

> **podría** es del condicional o pospretérito y
>
> **pudo** es el pretérito simple

o sea ambas hablan de **eventos en el pasado**.

Diferente es el caso en que se use **podría** sin el verbo auxiliar **haber** (y con morir en el infinitivo). Ahí si *"podría"* denota una posibilidad en el futuro.

> Ella podría morir por decapitación.

Puedes ir a la RAE y buscar "[poder](http://dle.rae.es/?id=TU1KCfY)" y al lado ves el botón que dice conjugar.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Si bien (como dice DGaleano) ambas oraciones pueden transmitir el mismo significado de hipótesis pasada (no cumplida o contrafactual), existe un significado de "pudo" que no es expresado por "podría", el de posibilidad en el pasado.

Supongamos que Uma Thurman efectivamente murió (se la encontró decapitada, además de con otras lesiones) y se están barajando distintas hipótesis sobre su muerte. Un médico forense podría decir:

- Uma **pudo** haber muerto por decapitación. (Uma murió, y es posible que haya ocurrido por decapitación.)